# Считается ли редактирование сообщение телеграм-ботом как отправка?

Tags: php, telegram-bot, telegram

В телеграм боте есть лимит а отправку 30 сообщений в секунду (не запросов). Считается ли редактирование сообщения как отправка? Т.к. На этом можно хорошо сэкономить время

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, к сожалению, бот не сможет отправлять или редактировать более 30 сообщений в секунду. В группе @BotTalk уже несколько раз отвечали на этот вопрос.

Comment: Спасибо! Даже не знал, что есть такая группа)

Comment: можно еще задавать вопросы касательно API официальному аккаунту поддержки @BotSupport, но ответ придется достаточно долго ждать.